# Excel Formula to Compare Cell to Range then Give Answer

Tags: excel, range, formula

I need a formula to compare one cell to a range and then depending on where the cell falls into the range, tell me how many more of something I need to get the original cell above the next highest number in the range. The range is only 4 numbers that are fixed.

Below is an image to hopefully help visualize what I want. Where it says "You will need at min x more Power..." is where I need the formula to go. I basically want the 'x' to be a number 1-4 depending on how the Power Pool: Available (W) number falls into the range under 15.4W/Port table in the lower left corner.

So right now you can see that I have 3 Switches and the Power Pool Available is only at 1275W. Looking at the table in the bottom left corner you can see that with 3 Switches that number needs to be at least 2328.48W.

Hope I've given enough info and I apologize if there is already an answer somewhere. Thanks in advance!
[image: stack power calc]

*Updated with Row and Column identifiers

*Update:
I know what I want in my head, I'm just having a hard time getting it out my fingertips!

Basically I want cell C24 to tell me how many more power supplies i need(either 0,1,2,3, or 4) based on where cell K21 falls into the range E28:E31. 
I'm thinking what I might actually need is for line 24 to tell me how many more watts I need vs how many more power supplies. Because in real life, there are a few options of power supplies available.

I've tried a few IF statements but if I change it to how many more watts I need I might actually be able to figure it out.

So with that, since I'm currently using 3 Switches and according to my table at the bottom I would need 2328.48W of power to supply 15.4W of power to each port. Cell K21 is only at 1275W so I want cell C24 to tell me that I need 1053.48 more Watts of Power, at min.

Hope this helps! Thanks again!

Comment: I've read it twice, and I'm still confused...  If the number is 1275, and because it's three switches you need at least 2328.48.  I think I can show you how to return the 2328.48 based on the number 3, but I don't understand how that translates into an integer for the number of power supplies.  Can you clarify?

Comment: it's not clear which data you want to use in your formula and which "thinking" you want to use. Please explain (also show column/rows index in the image and refer to the coordinates for us to understand)

Comment: I just updated with a better picture and hopefully better detail!